# how to insert array or multi value in mysql with in one insert execution

Tags: php

`$a` is an array.

```
if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test_mysql (id) VALUES (".implode("),(",$a).")"))
{
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
else
{
    echo 'thank you';
}
```

can you give me any batter idea:

Comment: As long as the values in your array `$a` are already known to be valid and sane, the method you have is just fine, and not uncommon.  Emphasis on _known to be valid and sane_.

Comment: Unlike the code indentation in the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about printing example of how content of $a looks like?
"$a is an array" is not enough. print it and see how your query looks like.
for example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test_mysql (id) VALUES (".implode("),(",$a).")";
print $query;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO test_mysql (id) VALUES '.implode(',', $a));
```